# Migrate Certificate from certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1 to cert-manager.io/v1

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I am migrating **Certificate** from `certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1` to `cert-manager.io/v1`, however, I am getting this error

> error validating data: ValidationError(Certificate.spec): unknown field "acme" in io.cert-manager.v1.Certificate.spec

My manifest

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
  - myapp.com
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: google-dns
      domains:
      - '*.myapp.com'
      - myapp.com
```

I know that there is no more `acme`, but how to migrate to a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

The `cert-manager.io/v1` API version separates the roles of certificate [issuers](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/) and certificates.

Basically, you need to [configure](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/) a certificate issuer among the supported ones, like [ACME](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/).

This issuer can be later used to obtain a certificate.

Please, consider read this tutorial about a certificate obtained from ACME with DNS validation in the [cert-manager.io documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/dns-validation/#issuing-an-acme-certificate-using-dns-validation).